# Can I cross into USA on the day my visa expires

Tags: visas, usa, visa-expiration

My wife is a (Mexican national) her visa expires on June 3rd, can she cross into the US from Mexico on that day?  Or does her Visa expire at midnight on the 2nd or midnight on the 3rd?
We will be driving across and returning same day.

Comment: Do you have a credible plan to vacate the US by that evening?connecting flight etc.?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes; your visa expires on midnight at the end of the 3rd." Furthermore, if you've been in Mexico for fewer than 30 days, having traveled there from the US, you can even enter the US after your visa expires, thanks to [automatic revalidation](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date/auto-revalidate.html).

Comment: @Harper there's no need to vacate the US by that evening.  See [What the Visa Expiration Date Means](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date.html).